# Multiple file upload ajax java

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, jquery-file-upload

I have requirement of uploading mutiple files but size of these files should be less than 10 MB. I tried with .ajaxfileupload, i couldn't pass any messages from action class to javascript. Json results are not geeting passed. I started trying with GWT. But couldn't integrate the client side - javascripts, css, and html portion. any help on this regard? Also it should support in all browsers.

When i integrate GWT MultipleUpload, how to change gwtuploadsample.MultipleUploadSample.nocache.js, so that components will be listed on page. When i integrate i don't see any components listed in page with browse option. Js is not getting loaded correctly.

Comment: It seems your project is not a GWT application, but you need an ajax solution to upload files and you came to gwtupload examples, right? Could you elaborate a bit more your architecture, what is your server side framework? is your app a RIA app (single page)?

Comment: My ajaxFileUpload.js is working now. i am proceeding with that.thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)